# How to plot longitudinal data in R

Tags: database, r, rstudio, user-groups, average

I am trying to plot longitudinal data in R. My data frame has this form:

participant_ID  group    S1    S2    S3    S4    S5    S6    S7    S8
1 ctrl 14.00 14.00 13.00 13.00  7.00  8.00  4.00  1.00
2 drug  2.00 13.00 13.00 16.00 14.00  6.00  6.00  6.00
3 ctrl 27.00 28.00 29.00 35.00 30.00 17.00 17.00 18.00
4 drug 17.00 14.00  8.00 15.00 14.00  5.00 16.00 13.00
5 drug  8.00  2.00 29.00 27.00  8.00  6.00  7.00  7.00

....

I have 8 timepoints ("S"). I want a graph with two lines representing the groups and lines representing the evolution of the measure across the timepoints (From S1 to S8). I was trying to use plot.ts (My_data[,3:10]), but with this command I got individual graphs corresponding to a single timepoint. Does anyone have another suggestion?

YIDA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach is to use the `lattice` package which will permit you examine the individual growth curves for each subject.  However you will need to reshape your data into long format first.

```
df<-structure(list(participant_ID = 1:5, group = c("ctrl", "drug", 
"ctrl", "drug", "drug"), S1 = c(14L, 2L, 27L, 17L, 8L), S2 = c(14L, 
13L, 28L, 14L, 2L), S3 = c(13L, 13L, 29L, 8L, 29L), S4 = c(13L, 
16L, 35L, 15L, 27L), S5 = c(7L, 14L, 30L, 14L, 8L), S6 = c(8L, 
6L, 17L, 5L, 6L), S7 = c(4L, 6L, 17L, 16L, 7L), S8 = c(1L, 6L, 
18L, 13L, 7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

library(reshape2)
df2<-melt(data=df,id.vars = c("participant_ID","group"))

library(lattice)
xyplot(data=df2, value~variable |participant_ID)
```

You could aggregate this to get one line representing all cases if you wish.  It is very important to examine the individual growth curves first.  [See this document](http://gseacademic.harvard.edu/~alda/pdf%20files/Contents%20of%20ALDA.pdf) for details.

Comment: @Yacila, glad the answer helped.